# Nagios: monitor http service on a different port

Tags: http, nagios

I want to monitor services over http running on multiple ports other than 80.
Services are running on port 8083, 8086 and some other ports. I created server.cfg file as follows:

```
define host {
        use                     linux-server
        host_name               cfbase-prod
        alias                   cfbase-prod
        address                 x.x.x.x
        contacts                admin
        }

define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       cfbase-prod
        service_description             HTTP
        check_command                   check_http
        contacts                        admin
        check_interval                  1
        }
```

But it is not working in my nagios console it still shows as the http on port 80, which is not the case. Can somebody please help.

Comment: `check_http -p 8083`

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the port number directly in the command but you will must create one command per tested port.

Or you can create a custom variable to store the port number , with your example:

```
define host {
        use                     linux-server
        host_name               cfbase-prod
        alias                   cfbase-prod
        address                 x.x.x.x
        contacts                admin
        }

define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       cfbase-prod
        service_description             HTTP
        check_command                   check_http
        contacts                        admin
        check_interval                  1
        _port_number                    8083
        }
```

And on your command you can inherite of this variable like this :

```
define command{
    command_name check_http 
    command_line $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ -p $_SERVICEport_number$ $ARG1$ 
}
```

You must prepend `_service` for a service or `_host` for a host to use your variable in a command.
source :

https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/customobjectvars.html

Comment: Just a note to say that when I tried this in version 4.3.4, I needed to capitalise the custom variable name in the command: `... -p $_SERVICEPORT_NUMBER$`

Answer (score 3):

When I look at the check_http and the $ARG all should be in place already, so why not just use:

```
check_http!-p 8888
```

to request the probe. At least my short test worked for me with nagios4.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a new command, perhaps named `check_http_port` that takes a port as `$ARG1$`.

```
define command {
    command_name check_http_port
    command_line $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ -p $ARG1$ <other options you use>
}
```

And then use that in your service definition, as `check_http_port!8083`.

See `check_http --help` for more options/info.